# svn list command error 200 on an Apache+SVN server setup

Tags: svn, apache, svn-config

I'm setting up an Apache+SVN server for work. I can checkout a repository, but when I run the svn list command I get the following error "OPTIONS of 'https://server': 200 OK (https://server)"

Here is my subversion.conf

```
 <Location /svn/>

   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /svn/repos/
   # Require SSL connection for password protection.
   SSLRequireSSL

   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "NH SVN"
   AuthUserFile /svn/repos/users
   Require valid-user

 </Location>
```

If I remove the trailing / I get 403 forbidden errors when I run the same command.

Comment: Actually, 200 is not an error, on contrary it's status code that tells that everything is OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not list repositories. Only files IN a repository. So you need to create a repository first at /svn/repos/ using "svnadmin create". Dont forget to give apache rw-rights on the new repository

```
svnadmin create /svn/repos/mynewrepository
svn list https://serverurl/svn/mynewrepository
```

SVNParentPath means you can have multiple repositories under this path.

Comment: Oh I forgot! For Weblisting:

option SVNListParentPath On|Off

"When set to On, allows a GET of SVNParentPath, which results in a listing of all repositories under that path. The default setting is Off."
I am not sure this will enable svn list to get a repository list.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. I guess I will go back to using svnserve.